# why volatile can't be used in the case where one more threads will write value

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

Many documents hints that we can't use `volatile` when one more threads will write value,for example,there is a boolean object `isRun`,if two threads or more invoke `setIsRun(true/false)`,we can't use `volatile` to decorate variable `count`.

As i know,`volatile` can make newest value visible to all threads,then why we can't use it in above case?Anyone can tell me about this,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said.

`volatile` - Guarantees Visibility amongst Threads.

`synchronized` - Guarantees Atomicity and Visibility amongst Threads.

Example:

Assume there are two threads A and B both have access to following variable.

```
public volatile int count = 0;
```

If Thread A does the following

```
count++;
```

It is not guaranteed that the JVM execute `++` operation which is actual 3 JVM operations (read, increment, write) atomically. There are chances that Thread B seeing stale value being assigned to `count` if and when there are race conditions.

If you want atomicity you need to use `synchronized`

Example:

Assume there are two threads A and B both have access to following variable and `increment` method.

```
private volatile int count = 0;

public synchronized void increment() {
    count++;
}
```

Now if Thread A enters the `increment` method it will acquire an instance level monitor lock which it will only release when it exists the `increment` method. This guarantees that JVM instructions read, increment, write executes one after the other.

Comment: The question is about a boolean.

Comment: Sorry,I have updated the question to be about with `boolean` variable,so it's won't be relevant to atomicity.